# How to exclude element without id or class in php xpath query

Tags: php, domxpath

I have this:

```
crawl($next_page,"//div[@class='a__content cf']/p|//div[@class='a__content cf']/div");
```

it returns all text nodes in the class/p and class/div and all their children. But I want it to exclude class/p/strong

Comment: Have a look at `and not()`

Comment: How do I use it? I keep getting errors

Comment: PHP doesn't support XPath v2.0. So you may want to change / remove xpath tag.

Comment: @revo what do I use instead of that?